# entity - relationship builder software

Tags: data-analysis, data

i'm looking for some kind of software that would let me create "entities" (people, places, things, etc) with different characteristics (to be set by me) and tags. Then the software should be able to link these together as desired. I also need to import data automatically from a database. Any ideas what something like this might be?

Comment: *What for*? How would it operate if you *set* characteristics and tags? Import from a database *in what structure*? Price? OS? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Comment: Nothing yet if you [search the site for ERD](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+erd)?